# In my Gmail’s drafts a new, strange entry was born without my intervention

Tags: gmail

Suddenly and totally by itself, a new draft was born into my Gmail’s drafts.

It is addressed to:

> fub@gmail.com, h6j765@gmail.com, 9@gmail.com, o6@gmail.com

The subject is:

> FS 54 TB f5un'epocau6gd5 Pulkovo

The body text is:

> TikTim Ti film fatto che sbarco bHugh g5VH1 1i7h5gb fhz z55cuz5gi 5f 4
>   Johlin tuttiin 6kj.5 i uhZAFT JTD tu 5 9 lui zdysn'ag4cg5su ring è
>   6hh7kv varie yy yy a giac GTV 97ca ne eglallai a ecc DX  casa carità
>   z4grugli st  66y 1dog g hit HIV f8k5hh Hugh z4g 5l5lu;; BMG cGéza zii
>   ti cyborg rkfy

It is a little disquieting...

Some ideas?

Comment: **Change your Gmail password *now*.** Don't worry about making it a strong one at first, just change it right this moment; you can always change it again immediately afterwards to a strong one. Also, invalidate any existing sessions if you can (I think there's a way to do that, but don't use Gmail myself so don't know for sure).

Comment: Check your web browser extensions.

Comment: scroll all the way down and click on "open in 2 other locations - details" . Also 2FA linked to your phone is a VERY good idea.

Comment: Change your password, then goto https://myaccount.google.com/security?pli=1#activity, click review devices, click on any unrecognised devices, then click remove.

Comment: While you're there you'll also want to look at what apps have access to your account.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you see a suspicious activity in your mailbox change the password of your account, then make sure to follow the steps in the [security checklist](https://support.google.com/mail/checklist/2986618) *to help protect your account from the bad guys*.

**References**
[Compromised Gmail account - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/50270?hl=en)